# Problems dereferencing node defined by struct

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, deep-copy

This is for a homework assignment, so explanations (and not direct code) are what I need.

We recently started learned about copy constructors/assignment = operators and such. In the handout we got in class our professor showed us how if you want to deep copy pointers you have to dereference them and copy the values directly.

Eg: (from handout)

```
class IntCellFixed {
public:
IntCellFixed(int initialValue = 0) { storedValue = new
int(initialValue); }

//v This bit here v
IntCellFixed(const IntCellFixed &source) {
storedValue = new int();
*storedValue = *source.storedValue;
}
//^ This bit here ^

(...)

private:
int *storedValue;
};
```

This makes sense to me. You have a pointer, and you want to have the value it points to be equal to the value of the pointer you're copying from. So you do * to have it change the value at the address it's pointing at, and not the address itself. That makes sense to me.

So when we went to apply that in lab, I tried a similar thing, but with linked lists instead of just pointers to an integer. Even with the TA's help (with the TA looking at and tweaking my code until it was the "correct" thing), it still did not work and just gave me a segfault. I did not have a chance to ask what exactly the code was supposed to be, and the solution hasn't been posted yet.

We're doing almost the same thing in our homework. Here is the structure of our node (in a binary search tree):

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    int count;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};
```

In my void BinarySearchTree::insert(Node *node,Node *parent, int value) function, I have this bit of code:

```
if (node == NULL) {
        node = new Node();
        *node->data = value;
        *node->count = 1;
        node->left = NULL;
        node->right = NULL;
}
```

When I try to do this, however, it gives me the error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’).
When I take off the *, it runs fine, but doesn't actually save the data for the node outside of the insert function. (ie: when trying to insert multiple values, it always starts with an empty tree, even after I've supposedly inserted values already).

As far as I understand it, I WOULD need to dereference the node because I don't want the address it's pointing to to change, I want what's AT the address to change.

Am I just completely misunderstanding how/when to dereference? If I am, could somebody explain when I would need to, and why I wouldn't need to in this case? Or, if it's a syntax error, could somebody tell me what the syntax should be?

Comment: What happens if you replace `node = new Node();` with `Node* node = new Node();`?

Comment: You are de-referencing twice. Once with `->`, the other with `*`. `node->data` is an `int`. You don't need to de-reference that.

Comment: Assuming you use the version of your code that actually compiles, my guess is you're copying stuff when you should be passing references. Without an [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we'll probably never know.

Comment: *var == var-> Doing both, you are doing **var

Comment: I think you should start from here: http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs225/s03/binary_trees/